# Annoying YouTube mixes always lead to the same songs

Tags: youtube, autoplay

YouTube used to be able to allow me to discover new music etc.

For some time now though, it's driving me crazy. All mixes which *allegedly* are "Non-stop playlists based on a song or artist" eventually become more or less the same set of songs I heard so many times before.

It seems like each mix is based in much larger part on my viewing history rather than the song or artist the mix starts from.

Because of the autoplay, I hear them over and over again. Starting songs of those mixes also are more or less the same songs I heard hundreds of times. All of this seem to aggravate the situation.

Is there a way of fixing this? Some settings where you can reset or alter the behavior of the so called AI?